# Scenarios where merge sort is preferred over quick sort

Tags: algorithm-analysis, sorting, quicksort, mergesort

As merge sort and quicksort both have the same average time complexity of $O(n \log(n))$. In which scenarios would merge sort be preferred over quicksort when sorting data?

Comment: This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70402/why-is-quicksort-better-than-mergesort) can help you.